Linux script running cat on a remote server
I have a script on Linux Rhel 8 which tries to run commands remotely via ssh
#!/bin/bash
SERVER=$1
USER=$2
PATH1="/mypath"
FILE="myfile"
ssh $USER@$SERVER << EOF
cd "$PATH1"
DATE_SUFFIX="\$(date +%Y%m%d)"
cp "$FILE" "$FILE_\$DATE_SUFFIX"
FILE_CONTENT="\$(cat "$FILE)"
EOF

The cp command works as expected, but the cat command does not  produce any output. If I add the line
cat "\$FILE" > output.txt

then output.txt is empty.
What is the correct way to run the cat command remotely ?
Ultimately, the script will also run
echo $FILE_FORMAT

on the local server, so the second question is: how would the remote variable be passed back to the local server ?

is $FILE already populated before you run the remote command? And where does $FILE2 come from?

Is this the exact script you're using? Because then there is a typo and cat "$FILE2 should have been cat "$FILE". Also be aware that $PATH is a special environment variable and you should use another name for your script.

Sorry, I am not able to copy/paste script from the source so I am typing it by hand, and there were a few typos which I have now corrected.

cat "\$FILE" > output.txt  no need to escape the $ here, the variable is from your side, not the ssh target. In contrast to FILE_CONTENT which will be local to the ssh target

Have you really corrected all the typos? You're still missing the end quote in cat "$FILE. Maybe you should wait until you get to a place where you can copy/paste.

\$DATE_ is not \${DATE}_ -- the underscore is a valid variable-name character so you need to use the curly braces. Separately, this general approach to forming commands to run with ssh (via string concatenation) is a source of major security risks.

...assuming bash 5.0+, the easy fix is to use ${var@Q} when generating strings intended to be eval'd by another shell. (Also, those variables don't need to be quoted, so if you ran path=/mypath, then you ran use cd ${path@Q} when generating code for use by ssh).

That said, as a whole, this is more than one problem to a question -- you've got the $DATE vs $DATE_ issue, and the how-do-I-pass-results-to-the-host question. Those both have existing duplicates, and if asked separately they could be closed with those duplicates; correspondingly, that makes the question overall too broad to be on-topic.

(and you have the same problem with $FILE vs $FILE_ as you have with $DATE vs $DATE_ -- if you're concatenating variables with following strings that are also valid in variable names, use curly quotes or separate quoting! -- by "separate quoting", I mean something like "$FILE"_"$DATE" -- note that the variable expansions are in quotes, and the constant string like _ is unquoted)

@CharlesDuffy I prefer to recommend ${FILE}_${DATE}

@Barmar, ...and that's the approach I recommended in my first comment in the series. ("curly quotes" instead of "curly braces" in the last one was a thinko, flippin' 5-minute edit window...)

Remember, ssh is just a program running on your local system that has output like any other. What it's doing is running commands remotely, and its output depends on theirs...
$: unset f
$: f="$(ssh "$user@$server" "tee '$path/${file}_'\$(date +%Y%m%d) < '$path/$file'" 2>/tmp/login.stuff)"
$: echo "$f"
Hello, World!


I threw the motd/system login boilerplate stuff to /tmp/login.stuff to eliminate nonrelevant noise for this example.
You have to set the variable locally if you want it set locally. I set it with the stdout from the ssh. To do that, you have to be careful that nothing else generates unwanted output. For example, POSIX cd will sometimes report the directory (see the manpage). Better to use full paths anyway.
Generally better to use lowercase variable names - then you don't have to say PATH1 to keep from trashing $PATH...
I used tee to make a copy of the file and return its content in one pass since you weren't explicitly using cp -p.

